# Python - Recursive function to serialise family tree information into JSON

Tags: python, json, recursion, tree

I am having difficulty creating a function that will produce a family tree in JSON format.

An example of a two parent, two offspring tree can be seen here:

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 409,
            "name": "Joe Bloggs",
            "no_parent": "true"
        },
        {
            "children": [
                {
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 411,
                    "name": "Alice Bloggs"
                },
                {
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 412,
                    "name": "John Bloggs"
                }
            ],
            "hidden": "true",
            "id": "empty_node_id_9",
            "name": "",
            "no_parent": "true"
        },
        {
            "children": [],
            "id": 410,
            "name": "Sarah Smith",
            "no_parent": "true"
        }
    ],
    "hidden": "true",
    "id": "year0",
    "name": ""
}
```

Joe Bloggs is married to Sarah Smith, with children Alice Bloggs and John Bloggs. The empty nodes exist purely to handle vertices in the tree-map diagram (see jsfiddle below).
The above example should help explain the syntax. A more complex tree can be found on this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/0vbtvoon/22/
The JSON associated with the jsfiddle can be found from lines 34 to lines 101.

I am having difficulty writing a function that recursively produces the JSON for a family tree. I begin with a `person` class that represents the oldest member of the family. The function would then checks for marriages, for children etc and continues until the tree is complete, returning the json.

My code involves a `person` class as well as an associated `marriage` class. I have appropriate methods such as ids for each person, get_marriage() function, get_children() methods etc. I am wondering the best way to go about this is.

My attempt at a recursive function can be found below. The methods/functions involved etc are not detailed but their purpose should be self-explanatory. Many thanks.

```
def root_nodes(people, first_node=False): #begin by passing in oldest family member and first_node=True
    global obj, current_obj, people_used
    if obj is not None: print len(str(obj))
    if type(people) != list: 
        people = [people]
    for x in people:
        if x in rootPeople and first_node: #handles the beginning of the JSON with an empty 'root' starting node.
            first_node = False
            obj = {'name': "", 'id': 'year0', 'hidden': 'true', 'children': root_nodes(people)}
            return obj
        else:
            marriage_info = get_marriage(x)
            if marriage_info is None: #if person is not married
                current_obj = {'name': x.get_name(), 'id': x.get_id(), 'children': []}
                people_used.append(x)
            else: 
                partners = marriage_info.get_members()
                husband, wife = partners[0].get_name(), partners[1].get_name()
                husband_id, wife_id = marriage_info.husband.get_id(), marriage_info.wife.get_id()
                marriage_year = marriage_info.year
                children = marriage_info.get_children()
                people_used.append(partners[0])
                people_used.append(partners[1])
                if partners[0].get_parents() == ['None', 'None'] or partners[1].get_parents() == ['None', 'None']:
                    if partners[0].get_parents() == ['None', 'None'] and partners[1].get_parents() == ['None', 'None']:
                        current_obj = {'name': str(husband), 'id': husband_id, 'no_parent': 'true'}, {'name': '', 'id': 'empty_node_id_' + empty_node(), 'no_parent': 'true', 'hidden': 'true', 'children': root_nodes(children)}, {'name': str(wife), 'id': wife_id, 'no_parent': 'true', 'children': []}               
                    if partners[0].get_parents() == ['None', 'None'] and partners[1].get_parents() != ['None', 'None']:
                        current_obj = {'name': str(husband), 'id': husband_id, 'no_parent': 'true'}, {'name': '', 'id': 'empty_node_id_' + empty_node(), 'no_parent': 'true', 'hidden': 'true', 'children': root_nodes(children)}, {'name': str(wife), 'id': wife_id, 'children': []}
                    if partners[0].get_parents() != ['None', 'None'] and partners[1].get_parents() == ['None', 'None']:
                        current_obj = {'name': str(husband), 'id': husband_id}, {'name': '', 'id': 'empty_node_id_' + empty_node(), 'no_parent': 'true', 'hidden': 'true', 'children': root_nodes(children)}, {'name': str(wife), 'id': wife_id, 'no_parent': 'true', 'children': []}              
                else:
                    if not any((True for x in partners[0].get_parents() if x in people_used)):
                        current_obj = {'name': str(husband), 'id': husband_id, 'no_parent' : 'true'}, {'name': '', 'id': 'empty_node_id_' + empty_node(), 'no_parent': 'true', 'hidden': 'true', 'children': root_nodes(children)}, {'name': str(wife), 'id': wife_id, 'children': []}
                    elif not any((True for x in partners[1].get_parents() if x in people_used)):
                        current_obj = {'name': str(husband), 'id': husband_id}, {'name': '', 'id': 'empty_node_id_' + empty_node(), 'no_parent': 'true', 'hidden': 'true', 'children': root_nodes(children)}, {'name': str(wife), 'id': wife_id, 'no_parent': 'true', 'children': []}
                    else:
                        current_obj = {'name': str(husband), 'id': husband_id}, {'name': '', 'id': 'empty_node_id_' + empty_node(), 'no_parent': 'true', 'hidden': 'true', 'children': root_nodes(children)}, {'name': str(wife), 'id': wife_id, 'children': []}
                return current_obj
            if obj is None:
                obj = current_obj
            else: 
                obj = obj, current_obj
            if people.index(x) == len(people)-1:
                return obj
```

Even though the function above is badly written - it is almost successful. The only instance where it fails is if one child is married, then the other children   are missed out from the JSON. This is because `obj` is returned without going to the next iteration in the `for loop`. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: you should really post an example input and the expected output, this must be doable way more easily